# POST Values not showing up in Loop

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I am trying to POST values from a form. I put a while loop and the loop seems to be working alright but when I try to POST the variable values, it doesn't show anything after the first value. How can I fix this please ?

```
$i=1;
while ($i<6) {
"$expense".$i=$_POST["expense".$i];
echo "$expense".$i;
$i++;
}
```

ADD INFO:
The var_dump shows this:

```
 ["expense1"]=> string(3) "100" ["amount"]=> string(0) "" ["type1"]=> 
string(6) "Select" 
["expense2"]=> string(3) "200" ["amount2"]=> string(0) "" ["type2"]=> string(6) "Select" 
["expense3"]=> string(3) "300" ["amount3"]=> string(0) "" ["type3"]=> string(6) "Select" 
["expense4"]=> string(0) "" ["amount4"]=> string(0) "" ["type4"]=> string(6) "Select" 
["expense5"]=> string(0) "" ["amount5"]=> string(0) "" ["type5"]=> string(6) "Select"
```

The HTML Code is here:

```
Expenses<br />
    <input name="expense1" type="text" id="expense1" />
    <input name="amount" type="text" id="amount" />
    <select name="type1" id="type1">
    </select>
    <br />
    <input name="expense2" type="text" id="expense2" />
    <input name="amount2" type="text" id="amount2" />
    <select name="type2" id="type2">
    </select>
    <br />
    <input name="expense3" type="text" id="expense3" />
    <input name="amount3" type="text" id="amount3" />
    <select name="type3" id="type3">
    </select>
    <br />
    <input name="expense4" type="text" id="expense4" />
    <input name="amount4" type="text" id="amount4" />
    <select name="type4" id="type4">
    </select>
    <br />
    <input name="expense5" type="text" id="expense5" />
    <input name="amount5" type="text" id="amount5" />
    <select name="type5" id="type5">
    </select>
    <br />
```

Comment: Show us the result of `var_dump($_POST);`, please. And show us your HTML form.

Comment: This code, I don't think it does what you think it does. -- Read up on [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) and how to properly create them (`"$expense".$i` is not correct ) , or better yet, put it all into an array.

Comment: Thanks for the update. But having seen the comment above now, anyber is right -  `"$expense".$i=` makes no sense at all. I would also suggest just using an array for this purpose.

Comment: And there's nothing wrong with your form or your input data, so it was still worth showing us, to rule that out. Although, as an aside, "amount" is inconsistent with the pattern of the other input names, it should be "amount1" really. But it's not relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look what the actual id or name attributes of the fields are. You can either check the HTML form or better look at what is actually posted. Try F12 in the browser, go to the network tab, then post the form content and have a look at what is listed as the body of the request. Maybe the fields all have the same name, so only one of the values is sent? It's hard to tell without more details, e.g. the HTML markup.

**Update:** As the other commenters rightly observed, this line is the problem:

```
"$expense".$i=$_POST["expense".$i];
```

There's not really a need for a changing variable name, so how about this:

```
$i=1;
while ($i<6) {
    $currentExpense = $_POST["expense".$i];
    echo $currentExpense;
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: This is more of a comment than an actual solution or answer, it merely suggests some debugging steps. Once you have 50 reputation you can post comments. But until then please don't post comments as if they are answers to the question.